# Is there an easy way to identify c++ inner functions calls in arm64 assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering, arm64

I'm trying to reverse engineer a black box executable and currently I'm comparing it's content with another executable that I can compile identically to 1st exe.

And now the issue is many function calls in 1st exe are deeply buried methods of c++.

Like some function call inside basic string direct initialization constructor that for some reason frees memory. And I suppose there are a lot of constructors and method calls of c++ std data types.

Is there any way to make this part easier?

I think I can always play a guessing game and initialize bunch of data types => compile => disassemble => run a script for pattern matching to see if there is a hit.

But there are already a lot of data types and constructor overloads combinations. And also I can't read all inner guts of c++.

Some calls were easy, since there was error logging with data type name in message.

But some are just settings zeroes and calling (what looks like) a bunch of folded empty functions.

Comment: Nothing easy that I know of if you don't have symbols so your disassembly is all just numeric addresses.  But empty functions shouldn't normally be getting called at all, definitely not for templates where the definition would be visible at compile time, except in a debug build.  In a non-LTO build, non-template empty functions defined in a separate .cpp won't get inlined.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/; it's borderline off-topic here since it's not about writing programs.  (Some reverse-engineering questions are about things that programmers writing C++ or assembly also need to know, but this one isn't.  Also, the tag predates the existence of a separate site for questions like this.)  If / when you do re-ask over there, include at least one example of the disassembly you're looking at.

Comment: Some tools (like IDA) have function recognition features (like FLIRT and Lumina). These work well if you have the signature of the specific runtime used. There are tutorials to make your own FLIRT signatures, for example. C++ is not easy to RE.